# Reference existing resources in Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to reference an existing resource in cloudformation. I am looking for something similar to terraform’s datasource facility where I can find a resource by tag, etc. and then use a property such as Id.

I have an existing security group with a consistent name across accounts. If I could look up this SG in the template I could use the ID.

Azure does this. terraform does this.

Comment: If seems CF is quite limited and AWS has not provided a "Find" facility like Azure. I am deploying my CF using Terraform, that can "Find" the correct values based on resource type,  tags, names, etc...  I don't have time to write something that should be present:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something similar to terraform’s datasource facility where

Sadly, there is no such functionality in plain CFN. You would have to create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in a form of a **lambda function**. The function would use AWS SDK to query your existing resources and return their IDs or any other information you require back to your stack for further use.